# WCF Invalid enum value '1' cannot be deserialized into type

Tags: wcf, deserialization, soapui, datacontract

I have a WCF Service having an Enum:-

```
 [DataContract(Name = "PurchaseType")]
 public enum PurchaseType
 {
    [EnumMember]
    Hire Purchase= 0,
    [EnumMember]
    PCP = 1
 }
```

DataContract as below:-

```
[DataContract]
public class Purchase
{
    [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public PurchaseType Type{ get; set; }
}
```

The enum members have been marked with the "EnumMember" attribute as required - how when I call the method and pass in "1" - I get below error, this should work...

Any pointers appreicated...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may add the flags to DataContract like this:

```
[DataContract] [Flags]
```

You can check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.